# Create multiple Menu blocks from the same menu

Tags: 8, blocks, navigation

In Drupal 7, the Blocks page contained a link for 'Add menu block', from where you could create multiple menu blocks of the same menu.

In Drupal 8, menu blocks seem to be generated automatically, however only one-per-menu exists (two, if you have are using Superfish).

I have a main menu block that needs to be rendered in different ways, depending on the Content Type being displayed.

Most of my content has a menu position assigned, however one type does not as it has over 300 sibling nodes; I need the same menu to appear, just showing one level higher. The sidenav will normally show the parent page, with the current page and all sibling pages underneath:

```
Parent page
 - child 1
 - child 2
 - child 3 <current page>
 - child 4 etc...
```

For the special Content Type, I need this structure:

```
Grandparent page
 - Parent sibling 1
 - Parent sibling 2
 - Parent 
 - Parent sibling 3 etc...
```

This would have been pretty simple in D7 - have I missed something?

How can I render the same menu at different levels? I'd rather not have to clone the entire menu using Entity Clone just to expose part of it.

Comment: You can place a menu block multiple times and configure it differently, also the visibility conditions.

Comment: *facepalm* You're right. When searching for my menu block to add, I was using an incorrect term and it never showed up, so I assumed it wasn't available. I'm going to leave this up here so that if this happens to anyone else, hopefully it saves them the hassle.